# uncheck checkboxlist if one listitem selected

Tags: .net, checkboxlist

I have the following checkboxlist. I need to uncheck rest of list items when "None" is selected. How do I do that? Thanks

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">French</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Spanish</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Italian</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">German</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Portuguese</asp:ListItem>   
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Chinese</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">Japanese</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8">Russian</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="None">None</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**UPDATE:**
Translation to vb.net of answer below by Darin Dimitrov

```
 Public Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
   End Function

   Protected Sub CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndexChanged
   Dim listItems = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)() 
            Dim isNoneSelected = listItems.Any(Function(x) x.Value = "None" AndAlso x.Selected = True) 
       If isNoneSelected Then 
                     listItems.Where(Function(x) x.Value <> "None").ToList().ForEach(Function(x) InlineAssignHelper(x.Selected, False)) 
       End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Server side: subscribe for the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event and enable AutoPostBack:

   ```
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem Value="1">French</asp:ListItem> 
       <asp:ListItem Value="2">Spanish</asp:ListItem> 
       <asp:ListItem Value="3">Italian</asp:ListItem> 
       <asp:ListItem Value="4">German</asp:ListItem> 
       <asp:ListItem Value="5">Portuguese</asp:ListItem>   
       <asp:ListItem Value="6">Chinese</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="7">Japanese</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="8">Russian</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="None">None</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
   ```

   and in the code behind:

   ```
   protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var listItems = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>();
       var isNoneSelected = listItems.Any(x => x.Value == "None" && x.Selected == true);
       if (isNoneSelected)
       {
           listItems.Where(x => x.Value != "None").ToList().ForEach(x => x.Selected = false);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Client side: use javascript to detect when the user clicks on the None checkbox and uncheck the others.

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I have problems translating this into vb.net. Could you give some directions? Many thanks.

Comment: @netNewbi3, there are online C# -> VB.NET conversion tools: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ You may try it to convert the codebehind to VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks, I use those. however this time they didnt work. Thanks.

Comment: @netNewbi3, could you be a little more specific when you say *they didn't work*? Like for example show the code you have tried and a possible compile time or runtime error you are getting as I don't know how exactly do you expect people helping you by only saying it didn't work without explicitly saying **what** didn't work.

Comment: Hi, i was talking about the translators. I updated the question to include the translation I got for your code.

Comment: @netNewbi3, please don't use the comments section for posting large code snippets as they are not properly formatted. Could you go ahead and update your original post by including this code? Also don't forget to include any probable error message you might be getting.

Comment: @netNewbi3, try importing System.Linq

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Hi thanks again, most errors are gone after I imported System.Linq. However one remains (to do with 'InlineAssignHelper'), I edited my question to add this. Thanks for your help, I am not familiar with Linq

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">French</asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Spanish</asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Italian</asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">German</asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">Portuguese</asp:ListItem>   
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Chinese</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="7">Japanese</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">Russian</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>  
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNone" Text="None" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkNone_CheckedChanged" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

> Removed the "None" option
>   from the list so that we can unselect
>   "None" if the user decide
>   to make a language selection.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// clear the list
    /// and checked "none" as SelectedIndexChanged resets it
    /// </summary>
    protected void chkNone_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList1.ClearSelection();
        chkNone.Checked = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If a user makes a selection clear the "none" checkbox
    /// </summary>
    protected void cklWatchMoveVideosIf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkNone.Checked = false;
    }
```

> The checkboxlist and the checkboxOther could be added to an updatePanel to
>   prevent a full postback, which makes this a bit smoother.